# How to create the Windows equivalent of Linux variable

Tags: linux, windows, amazon-web-services, variables, command-line

I am trying to use my AWS CLI to create an AMI. Part of the instructions I am following have me creating a variable in the CLI, but the example uses Linux, and I am doing this from my Windows command line:

```
$image_id=$(aws ec2 create-image --instance-id $instance_id --name "My server" --description "An AMI for my webserver" --query ImageId --output text)
```

When I try the above in the Command Prompt, I get `image_id is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`. How would I get this variable (`image_id`) in Windows?

Comment: Try using powershell instead.

Comment: Hmm, I was hopeful that would work, but it did not.

Comment: That command should work in powershell. What error do you see?

Comment: The error I see is similar to what was in the command prompt: `The term ...  is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

Comment: If the answer worked for you, don't forget to accept it (green tick)

Answer (score 1):

The following will work in powershell:

```
$image_id=(aws ec2 create-image --instance-id $instance_id --name "My server" --description "An AMI for my webserver" --query ImageId --output text)
```